# How to parse AJAX by cURL?

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I am trying to parse this url:

```
https://halykbank.kz/presscenter/novosti
```

The news are loaded by AJAX. In network I found URL, that must show loaded news, but there only

```
{"result":false,"hint":"NO_AUTHORIZATION_DATA"}
```

Why I am getting this? Here the URL, that I think must show me loaded news:

```
https://backend.halykbank.kz/struct/category-items?categoryId=199&sort=position%20desc&offset=200&limit=100
```

Comment: Their AJAX is probably only for use on their own pages.  It may be protected by one-time tokens to keep you from using their private services without their approval.

Answer (score 0):

You must send these header

```
Auth-User-Id, Auth-Token, Auth-Time
```

Comment: And unless there is a public API that you are allowed to use, they probably are not going to tell you how to make these valid.

Comment: how to sent these headers, that alex78191 said?

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0


$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/user', ['auth' =>  ['user', 'pass']]);
echo $res->getStatusCode(); // 200
$json_string = $res->getBody();

$json_obj = json_decode($json_string); //return Object<BR>
$json_arr = json_decode($json_string,true); //return Array
```

Comment: Maybe there another solution to get data instead of CURL